# Uncaught TypeError:this.props.products.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, function

I am working with React and I am using a React video series for that. I did everything what the teacher did but i am taking this errors when i to examine the web page. Also when i want to see the web page i just seeing a white page.

```
Uncaught TypeError:this.props.products.map is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
The above error occurred in the <CategoryList> component:
```

Here is my code;
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CategoryList from "./CategoryList";
import Navi from './Navi';
import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { currentCategory: "", products: [] };

  changeCategory = category => {
    this.setState({ currentCategory: category.categoryName });
    this.getProducts(category.id);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProducts();
  }

  getProducts = categoryId => {
    let url="http://localhost:3000/products";
    if(categoryId){
      url+="?categoryId"+categoryId;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ products: data }));;
  }


  render() {
    let productInfo = { title: "ProductList", baskaBisey: "bisey" }
    let categoryInfo = { title: "CategoryList" }
    return (
      <div >
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Navi />
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs="4">
              <CategoryList
                currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory}
                changeCategory={this.changeCategory}
                info={categoryInfo} />
            </Col>
            <Col xs="8">
              <ProductList
                products={this.state.products}
                currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory}
                info={productInfo}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );


  }
}
```

CategoryList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap'

export default class CategoryList extends Component {
    state = {
        categories: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getCategories();
    }

    getCategories = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ categories: data }));;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.info.title}</h3>
                <ListGroup >
                    {this.props.categories.map(category => (
                        <ListGroupItem onClick={() => this.state.changeCategory(category)}
                            key={category.id}>
                            {category.categoryName}
                        </ListGroupItem>
                    ))}
                </ListGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

ProductList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Table } from 'reactstrap'

export default class ProductList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>
                    {this.props.info.title}
                </h3>
                <Table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>unit Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity Per Unit</th>
                            <th>Units In Stock</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.products.map(product => (
                            <tr key={product.id}>
                                <th scope="row">{product.id}</th>
                                <td>{product.productName}</td>
                                <td>{product.unitPrice}</td>
                                <td>{product.quantityPerUnit}</td>
                                <td>{product.unitsInStock}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also i have a db.json file and i am using that data for the web page.

How can i solve this errors?

Comment: On first render, `this.props.products` will not be an array and hence the error. Just add a check. `Array.isArray(this.props.products) && this.props.products.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occur when your API is not sending the response correctly or maybe no backend response is generated.
 It basically indicates that there is no value defined or set in the `products` state.

You may solve it by these following solutions :

1. `console.log(response.json())` To check if there is any response.
2. `this?.props?.info?.title` Use the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid accessing an `undefined` value.
3. Use [try..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to fetch data, so you can debug the code and catch errors.